# TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i get the following error even after adding name to my create_superuser function  in my models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
# Create your models here.
class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email,name,password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("email is required")
        email=self.normalize_email(email)
        user=self.model(email=email,name=name)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self,email,name,password):
        """creates new super user with details """

        user=self.create_user(email,name,password)
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class UserProfiles(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects=UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELD=['name']
    def get_fullname(self):
        return self.name
    def get_shortname(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__ (self):
        return self.email
```

and  i get the following kind of error when i tried to run python manage.py createsuperuser command

```
TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

i dont know where i my mistake is ?

any kind of help is appreciated 
thanks in advance

Comment: The parameter should be `username`, not `name`.

Comment: You need to pass a value to your function for the parameter 'name' or allow 'name' to be `None`. I would also use 'username' instead of 'name'.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i didn't get what exactly your approach is.why would it be as username instead of name ,any reason ??

Comment: I mean that the parameter of the *function* should be `username`. The reason is because that is the interface that you are supposed to provide.

Comment: tried adding username  but that's  of no use

Comment: I can't see any problem in your code. You keep getting the error?

Comment: yes ,even i cant understand what the problem is

Comment: Ohh yeah i think you forgot **s** in `REQUIRED_FIELD` **it has an "s" at the end** **`REQUIRED_FIELDS`**

Comment: @YusefBH bro it worked thanks for saving my day